# Does libvirt support vlan aware bridges?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, bridge, libvirt, vlan

I am using libvirt/kvm in Debian 10 with a vlan aware bridge device, and I am stuck trying to configure the network interfaces for my VMs. Does libvirt support vlans? When I do a search the only references I find have to do with OVS.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/nesanton/kvmvlan